# Strange behavior of js object. Can't get a value from a key

Tags: javascript, json, postgresql, error-handling, fastify

Faced a small problem while writing a backend on fastify + postgres. I have a user registration function on a website that under the hood contributes data to Postgres. I am now optimizing error handling and ran into a problem. I want to get data from object "err".

In my case object "err" looks like this:

```js
err: {
      "type": "DatabaseError",
      "message": "duplicate key value violates unique constraint \"users_login_key\"",
      "stack":
          error: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_login_key"
              at C:\Users\galec\Dev\Lottery\backend-lottery\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:526:17
              at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
              at async file:///C:/Users/galec/Dev/Lottery/backend-lottery/src/routes/register.js:46:13
      "length": 202,
      "name": "error",
      "severity": "ERROR",
      "code": "23505",
      "detail": "Key (login)=(alaverdyan) already exists.",
      "schema": "public",
      "table": "users",
      "constraint": "users_login_key",
      "file": "nbtinsert.c",
      "line": "649",
      "routine": "_bt_check_unique"
    }
```

The error occurs when transacting a new user into Postgres table "users". It doesn't matter in principle, because I'm intentionally causing the error, but just in case I'll give you a snippet of the function code:

```js
try {

  // database transaction logic

} catch (err) {
  app.log.error({
    msg: `Error adding user '${login}' to table 'users'`,
    'Error code': err.code,
    'Error type': err.type,
    'Message': err.message,
    'Detail': err.detail,
    'DB table': err.table,
    'DB constraint': err.constraint,
    'Stack': err.stack,
  })
}
```

I end up with an object that is **missing the type field**:

[image]

That's not all. If we call the following commands, we get an interesting result.

```js
app.log.error(err) // will output an 'err' object with a 'type' field
app.log.error({ err: err }) // will output an 'err' object with a 'type' field
app.log.error({ error: err }) // prints the 'err' object without the fields 'type ', 'message' and 'stack'
```

Screenshots: [app.log.error(err)](https://prnt.sc/RoSwFBWsQftw), [app.log.error({ err: err })](https://prnt.sc/2kJvGxPKzpSb), [app.log.error({ error: err })](https://prnt.sc/5Rm-ai7WiJHd).

I created an issue on the Pino github. have not yet answered.

What could be the problem? Why can't I access err.type?

Comment: It seems that your problem is not that "you can't access `type`", it's that `app.log.error({` handles it in a way you are not expecting. Log the `err` object directly and see what's in it. Are you sure that " object "err" looks like this:" in your `catch` too?

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv app.log.error(err) [outputs to the terminal](https://prnt.sc/JhLqn-0SPZVY)

Comment: JavaScript can be slightly unpredictable sometimes, but that does not take away the fact that properties cannot make themselves disappear… What does `app.log.error` do? Could the problem be caused by that method?

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv app.log.error - logs error events. The standard logger for fastify is Pino. I have logs saved to [file](https://prnt.sc/VQr0EoS98JFD) and output to the terminal at the same time. The behavior is the same there and there. Object 'err' contains 'type', but for some reason it is not displayed when trying to access it.

Comment: How do you know `err` contains a `type` property? Probably it's `undefined`.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv `app.log.error({msg: \`${err.type}\`})` outputs to the terminal [**`undefined`**](https://prnt.sc/G2UMFiFHNZhb)

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv I have updated the question. There is new information at the end.

Comment: So you have a function to which you pass an object and depending on the property names of that object you get different results. And since the value of said property is always the same there can be only one explanation: `app.log.error` is doing different things depending on what is passed to it, and, like you see in your screenshots, what it's doing is it manipulates the input. There's really nothin more to answer here. No clue what "Pino" is but since it's some third party code you only have two options: get help from them or avoid doing what you are doing.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv Thanks for your time. Pino is the default (built-in) Fastify logger. I will wait for a reply from Pino developers, and I will duplicate the question to Fastify developers. Then I will post the answer here. I will keep you informed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complete explanation.

First, replicate the issue:

```js
const Pino = require('pino')
const pg = require('pg')

const pino = Pino({
  serializers: {
    err: Pino.stdSerializers.err
  }
})

const myErr = new pg.DatabaseError('err-msg', 42, 'err-name')

pino.info('\n------------------: pino.error')
pino.error(myErr) // will output an 'err' object with a 'type' field

pino.info('\n------------------: pino.error({err})')
pino.error({ err: myErr }) // will output an 'err' object with a 'type' field

pino.info('\n------------------: pino.error({error})')
pino.error({ error: myErr }) // prints the 'err' object without the fields 'type ', 'message' and 'stack'
```

Then I realized that the `DatabaseError` does not have any `type` prop:

```js
const myErr = new pg.DatabaseError('err-msg', 42, 'err-name')
console.log("Has own property 'type'?", Object.hasOwnProperty.call(myErr, 'type'))
console.log("Is 'type' in error?", 'type' in myErr)
console.log('Object.getOwnPropertyNames:', Object.getOwnPropertyNames(myErr))
console.log("Value of 'type':", `${myErr.type}`)
console.log("Is 'type' enumerable?", Object.propertyIsEnumerable.call(myErr, 'type'))
```

The [`pg` source code confirms it](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/blob/cf24ef28ee2134b63576afba341452f8adfb8a4d/packages/pg-protocol/src/messages.ts#L97C36-L97C41)

Realize that `pino` adds the `type` by [reading the constructor name](https://github.com/pinojs/pino-std-serializers/blob/master/lib/err.js#L17):

[image: pino]

> What could be the problem? Why can't I access err.type?

So, to get the same output between `err` and `error` you need to update the `serialzier` option:

```js
const pino = Pino({
  serializers: {
    err: Pino.stdSerializers.err,
    error: Pino.stdSerializers.err
  }
})
```

Instead to read the `type` you need to write:

```js
const errType = myErr.constructor.name
```